# syncfusion_flutter_charts trading view

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a KLine chart. How to automatically adjust the min and max fields in yAxis when dragging and zooming to fit the currently displayed K-line area, which happens to be the lowest price and the highest price in this area?

primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
isVisible: true,
visibleMinimum: //current_diplay_zoon.lowest price,
visibleMaximum: //current_diplay_zoon.highest price,,
rangePadding: ChartRangePadding.additional,
),

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.